# How to reinvent WcfSvcHost.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq

I am cross posting because I not having much success on my Oct 17 2015 post: 
[My query in Microsoft Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1bab2e0-fcd4-4c37-8fee-444c232ec7c5/how-does-visual-studio-run-wcf-services-how-to-create-a-self-hosted-msmq-wcf-service?forum=wcf#843b422a-5bb5-4d17-ad06-0bee41cb7c5f). I am following the example at [Sample WCF/MSMQ demo that produces DLL that works with WcfSvcHost](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326909/Creating-a-WCF-Service-with-MSMQ-Communication-and). I'm using the simplified "No Security" version of the code. I've made only minor changes to the App.Config (like changing the computer name and added a throttle with :

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1" maxConcurrentInstances="1"/>
```

Here is my question:

How do I reinvent WcfSvcHost.exe so I can either use the service control manager (SCM or SC) or a command prompt to run my WCF service. This command works:

```
  WcfSvcHost.exe /Service:MSMQNoSecurityService.dll
       /config:MSMQNoSecurityService.dll.config
```

Microsoft explicitly states that this wcfSvcHost.exe is exclusively for debugging and not for production. Please see my source code below and stack trace for my attempts to reinvent wcfSvcHost.exe. The problem is that WcfSvcHost is reading the XML and doing something special that I am not doing in my source code. What is that? Can someone tell me what that is? Clearly I need to read that XML file and extract information from it to make some function calls to the WCF/Windows API but which ones?

Thank you.

Siegfried

Here is my source code that does not work:

```
namespace HostMSMQNoSecurity {
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var baseAddress = "net.msmq://km/private/TestQueue";
        using (var host = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(typeof(MSMQService))) {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMSMQService),  new System.ServiceModel.NetMsmqBinding(), baseAddress);
            host.Open(); // Exception is throw here
            Console.WriteLine("Service host running...... Hit return to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Binding validation failed because the binding's MsmqAuthenticationMode property is set to WindowsDomain but MSMQ is installed with Active Directory integration disabled. The channel factory or service host cannot be opened.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqVerifier.VerifySecurity(MsmqTransportSecurity security, Nullable`1 useActiveDirectory)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqVerifier.VerifyReceiver(MsmqReceiveParameters receiveParameters, Uri listenUri)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncodingBindingElement.InternalBuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.MaybeCreateListener(Boolean actuallyCreate, Type[] supportedChannels, Binding binding, BindingParameterCollection parameters, Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, ServiceThrottle throttle, IChannelListener& result, Boolean supportContextSession)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelListener(StuffPerListenUriInfo stuff, ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Uri listenUri, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, Boolean supportContextSession, IChannelListener& result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
   at HostMSMQNoSecurity.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\siegfried\Documents\WinOOP\Examples\WCF\C#\CodeProject\MSMQ Service With No Security\MSMQNoSecurityService\HostMSMQNoSecurity\Program.cs:line 14

Compilation exited abnormally with code 127 at Wed Oct 21 19:49:00
```